# Tilted Dirac cones and Lorentz invariance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, graphene

New materials called Type II Dirac semi-metals have been discovered. They have a tilted Dirac cone instead of the straight linear dispersion. These particles are said to break Lorentz invariance. How is the Lorentz invariance broken when there is a tilt in the Dirac cone?

Comment: Could you provide some references? I am interested in the mentioned topic, theoretical reviews/papers will be very useful for me

Comment: [link](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v10/74) Check this out. I am having trouble understanding how these are lorentz violating quasiparticles?

Comment: in the link you gave it is said "A Lorentz-violating quasiparticle is one whose momentum-energy relation depends on the direction it travels". Doesn't this gives the answer? (specifically, the tilted Dirac cone breaks rotational symmetry, so it will also break Lorentz symmetry)

Comment: @yyy So it breaks lorentz invariance only if the dispersion is tilted along one of the k axis, say kz right? If the Dirac cones are tilted in all three directions in the momentum space in such a fashion that all tilts are similar, then "the energy momentum relation would be the same along all three directions". Would this then be a violation of lorentz invariance? Is it even possible to have similar tilted cones in all three directions at the same time? this is where I am confused.

Comment: if all tilts are similar then it is not tilted, it just has different $v_F$... the "tilt" is the fact that it is not identical in all directions. if you can still write the dispersion as $E_{\bf k} = v_F |\bf{k}|$ then it is not tilted